# Write the coordinates of detected bounding boxes in a video to a txt or csv file

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, darkflow

so i am using darkflow to detect objects(hats) in a video. It detects people wearing the hats and draws bounding boxes around the hat in a video. Now I want to save the top right and bottom left coordinates of the detected bounding boxes into a txt or csv file for further processing. I wrote the code in opencv-python. I can display the video and it draws bounding box successfully but i don't know how to save the coordinates of the boxes. Any idea how to do it?

I am using Mark jay's code for my purpose

```
#import libraries
import cv2
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
import numpy as np
import time

#load model and weights and threshold 
option = {
    'model': 'cfg/yolo-5c.cfg',
    'load': 'bin/yolo.weights',
    'threshold': 0.15,
    'gpu': 1.0
}


tfnet = TFNet(option)

#open video file 
capture = cv2.VideoCapture('videofile_1080_20fps.avi')
colors = [tuple(255 * np.random.rand(3)) for i in range(5)]

#read video file and set parameters for object detection 
while (capture.isOpened()):
    stime = time.time()
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    if ret:
        results = tfnet.return_predict(frame) 
        for color, result in zip(colors, results):
            tl = (result['topleft']['x'], result['topleft']['y']) # show top left coordinate 
            br = (result['bottomright']['x'], result['bottomright']['y']) #show bottom right coordinate
            label = result['label'] # show label
            frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, tl, br, color, 7) 
            frame = cv2.putText(frame, label, tl, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 
1, (0, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        print('FPS {:.1f}'.format(1 / (time.time() - stime)))
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

So as you can see i can display the video and detect object which draws bounding boxes. Now my goal is to save the pixel coordinates of these bounding boxes, just the top left and bottom right one. Any ideas guys?

Comment: So you're asking how to write to a file?

Comment: No i am asking how to extract these predicted bounding box coordinates and then write them into a file

Comment: you're drawing them.. you know the coordinates

Comment: I drew them to train the classifier. Then i use the training result to detect object on a separate video on which i did not draw them. The bounding boxes are displayed on this new video. So i want to extract the coordinates into a csv or txt file from this new video. I am looking for coding help on how to extract the displayed bounding boxes into a file

Comment: Well, to make it clear, the `result` in your code is the set of coordinates right? Why don't you make a list and append it with the values from the result and then in your `else` write it to a .txt file?

Comment: @RickM.  yes the result is the set of coordinates. I will try it. Sounds nice

Comment: @Shameendra update if it works! Cheers!

Comment: @RickM. Sorry for the late reply but i wanted to give you feedback that it worked! Thanks a lot. If you make your comment an answer, i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'result' parameter in your code is the set of coordinates. You make a [list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) and append it with the values from the `result` and then in your 'else' write it to a .txt file.

Cheers!